# Strange GUID-named sub-webs

Tags: 2013, web

I'm wondering what is the purpose of this strange GUID-named sub-webs could be?
Is it somehow related to Workflows or so?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The SiteMaster feature creates sites with GUIDs in the URLs, but these are prefixed with "SiteMaster" and are not subsites. Can you navigate to these sites from the browser? What template was used to create the site. (should be listed in the SharePoint Manager properties) Is there a user listed in the "Author" property?

Comment: And, are you using any SharePoint "apps" / "add-ins" in the parent site?